# push to git server with ssh config file

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ssh

I have an AWS instance with git installed and a repo configured in /var/repo/mysite.git and a working directory in /var/www/mysite.com

And since my AWS instance doesn't provide root ssh access (and ssh is configured on a different access port), I also have a ~/.ssh/config file with;

```
    Host mysite.com 
     HostName path-to-ec2.amazon.com 
     User ubuntu
     Port 0000
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-ec2-pem-file
```

I can ssh like so with no problems:

```
ssh mysite.com
```

I can add my remote host like so with no problems:

```
git add remote mysite mysite.com:/var/repo/mysite.git
```

But when I try to do a push I get an error.

```
git push mysite master
```

Error:

> error: src refspec master does not match any.
>   error: failed to push some refs to 'mysite.com:/var/repo/mysite.git'

I've tried a number of varieties, including adding "ssh://user@..." with / without user and "ssh://".  I've tried changing the path to repo, etc.

I can't seem to push this repo in any way.  Can anyone please help me figure this out?

Comment: If you do have a local `master`, try `git push mysite -u  master:refs/heads/master`.

Answer (score 1):

So, seems like a couple things were wrong.. either my remote repo wasn't configured properly to see /var/www/... and /var/repos/...  or it wasn't setup properly as a --bare repo.

I've moved both the repo and working dir into my /home/ubuntu directory for now, and setup the repo with --bare flag, then setup a ./hooks/post-receive script to "checkout -f" on the repo/working directories, respectively.

Seems like I'm up and running now.

Answer (score 0):

This error message means the list of references (in this case, branches) you gave to push doesn't match anything in your local repository.  This is probably because the `master` branch doesn't exist on the local side.

Comment: no.. seems like it was an issue with the remote repo not being --bare (I'll post an answer below)